# displaying runtime errors in android/ios installed app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I've been trying to get errors to display in a text field within the app for ease of error reporting from users.

I've had some success using this code I found on stackoverflow. It's used at the top level of the app but it's not working on device:

```
//start code
this.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, errorHandler);  

function globalErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void  
{  
    var message:String;  
    //check for runtime error  
    if (event.error is Error)  
        message = (event.error as Error).getStackTrace();  
    //handle other errors  
    else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)  
        message = (event.error as ErrorEvent).text;  
    else  
        message = event.error.toString();  
    //do something with message (eg display it in textfield)  
    myTextfield.text = message;  
}  
//end code
```

At first this wouldn't work on the device and I thought it was because upon the error, when developing on the pc, flashplayer would display the actionscript popup with the error. Which you would need to click "dismiss all" or close and then the globalErrorHandler was called after and then the error written to the textfield. I thought this is what was keeping it from showing up on the device. However, by adding event.preventDefault() I was able to suppress the actionscript popup when developing on the desktop and the error was written to the textfield successfully. This was not the case however on the andriod device. It still just hangs on the error. It's as if the default error event cannot be suppressed on android.

Thanks for your time. Any help appreciated!

EDIT 22/09/2017: I was able to see the error on device finally. It had to do with while on desktop publishing the error would be shown. However, on device the behavior was different and something was covering the textfield, by bring it to the front on error I was able to see it. However, I still see that some errors deeper in the class hierarchy are not being caught.

Comment: What version of AIR are you using? In older versions, `getStackTrace()` would return `null` in non-debugger environments.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm using the latest version of air 26

Answer (score 1):

In our project we have it simpler (and it is working):

```
stage.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);

private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    // Console is basically a TextField for debug/diagnosis output.
    if (e.error) Console.error(e.error.getStackTrace());

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The other thing you should probably check is whether your **TextField** actually displays any text **at all** for there might be text embedding issues, unrelated to the error handling routine.

**UPD**: Loading SWFs so it doesn't mix with the parent.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path);

var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

var loader:Loader = new Loader;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.load(request, context);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried replacing my code with your simpler approach and it didn't work. I did check the textfield by setting some text to confirm it's visible on device and it was. However, your interaction had me tinkering more and I did determine that it is in fact working on device by creating a different error. The original error that would show up on desktop but not on the device was a Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. However, my app uses a database and creating an Error #3115 table already exists showed the error on device. Weird right?

Comment: As I test it more I find that even on the desktop testing, it doesn't always seem to catch the error and prevent the default popup from coming up when placed in various parts of the class hierarchy. And testing on the device it doesn't appear to display the error at all when it's a null exception like follows: 'var testnull:String = null; trace(testnull.toString());'

Comment: @cyboman Hmmm... Try subscribing to **stage.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents** instead of **this**.

Comment: I tried changing it to stage but that still didn't solve it not catching errors deeper in the hierarchy. Not sure why. It is in Main.as so I'm not sure why errors are not bubbling up.

Comment: also I should add that there was an issue with the textfield not being visible on device, I've edited them main post to reflect it. I can see errors being caught now however I'm still not getting ones deeper in the class hierarchy. The functionality as is is still useful however. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: what I'm finding is that the root or main class is only going to catch a runtime error and prevent the default behavior if the subclass can see it and doesn't have stage, parent etc... as null. Otherwise, the event won't propagate up, which makes sense. However, this limits seens to limit the usefulness of this technique for reporting or catching of such errors.

Comment: actually after more testing it doesn't appear the visibility of the parent has anything to do with it working consistently, maybe it's a bug?

Comment: @cyboman As far as I know, there's none. In my app this thing is working just fine. If there's an exception - it is getting caught and displayed. There are no cases of "it obviously fails but there are no exceptions" either. Maybe something else is at play here. Are your app is a whole thing? Or you load any additional modules with the code from several SWFs?

Comment: It's not that there is no exceptions, if I insert a runtime error, it will always show an error. It's that if injected in various parts of the code, it will sometimes not be caught by the top main class listener. Instead the default behavior is not prevented and it just shows the actionscript popup as usual and the listener never fires. At this point in testing, I have not tested errors in external swfs (there's only one that is an animation asset).

Comment: I'm testing more and it seems to be limited to one subclass. It's tough because it seems the behavior in general of this is inconsistent. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: so when you mentioned external swfs being a possible cause so I looked deeper. It seems the one class that's a problem has a preloader that loads some assets before actually calling the init function of the class. However, the asset has no code, it's animation is handled within the class that's loading. When the loader's event "added to stage" is fired. Then any error inserted anywhere after that in the class breaks and isn't captured at the main class. Not sure why adding a swf to the stage would break it.

Comment: Yep, if I insert the error after the loader is removed from the stage, then the error propogates up to main as expected. Any ideas why having an external swf on stage breaks this behavior?

Comment: @cyboman I have an idea so you might want to test it. You listen for the uncaught errors at **stage.loaderInfo**. Then you load another SWF that has its own **LoaderInfo** object at **Loader.contentLoaderInfo**. More to that, they both are in the same application sandbox and their classes and objects get mixed. See my updated post.

Comment: thanks for your input. I will definitely give that a try. Engaging with you has brought me a lot closer to understanding what's going on. Big props!

Comment: Also, do you use this approach on release builds of your applications? Do you know of any hits to performance using this method?

Comment: @cyboman There quite a lot of moves you can (or should) do before creating release builds, and these moves depend on what your app is, what platform you are aiming at and so on. One comment wouldn't start to cover all of that either.

Comment: of course, I'm just wondering if this error handling has any performance hits. Would you know of any official adobe guides online that speak to such preflight "moves". Super appreciative of your guidance so far!

Comment: @cyboman Nope, I don't know any. It's years of continuous experience for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, loading the loader in it's own application domain didn't fix the issue. It still doesn't catch the error after the external swf is loaded. Note that that swf has no code in it either. As soon as the swf is removed the error catching works.

Comment: @cyboman I encourage you to read about **LoaderContext** and **ApplicationDomain** and try variants they allow.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try next. Thanks!